# Vue cannot read property of undefined - Nested Object Access

Tags: vue.js

Vue is kicking an error in the console for "cannot read property (property name) of undefined". I've tried using v-if but still getting the error. It seems like the object doesn't exist or cannot be accessed like I have defined it, but I don't know why?

object defined in Vue as:

```
customerData:{
     address:{
          firstName:'',
          lastName:''
          }
     }
```

Html

```
 <div v-if="customerData.address.firstName">
      <input  v-model="customerData.address.firstName">
 </div>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're referencing the [`data`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#data) option in your directive binding, I think you should do :

```
<div >
  <input  v-model="address.firstName">
</div>
```

Comment: I just updated to clarify. object is "customerData.address.firstName"

Comment: ok you should check the existence of parent object like `v-if="customerData.address."`

Comment: If I look at the object using {{customerData.address.firstName}} notation the value appears. However, the error is still being thrown in the console.  I have tried with v-if and same result. Ill fire up a fiddle.

Comment: Thanks for your help on this. I was not able to replicate on fiddle (everything worked fine). I found the bug in the code which was caused the customerData object being overwritten by the response to a request when the page loaded. The "address" was not present in this response and therefore created the error.